# Problems inserting to database for android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, compiler-errors, insertion

When I trying to insert into my database I keep getting ERRORS listed below:

```
08-14 11:50:21.455: E/SQLiteLog(27688): (1) table exercises has no column named reps
08-14 11:50:21.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(27688): Error inserting reps=4 title=  BarBell Curls weight=4 notes=db date=August-14-2013
08-14 11:50:21.495: E/SQLiteDatabase(27688): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table exercises has no column named reps (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO exercises(reps,title,weight,notes,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Here is what I have for creation statement:

//Database creation sql statement

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                                            + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
                                            + DATE_SELECTED + " text not null, "
                                            + WEIGHT_INPUT + " text not null, "
                                            + REPS_INPUT + " text not null, "
                                            + KEY_BODY + " text not null" + ");";
```

//method to insert row

```
public long createExercise(String title, String date, String weight, String reps, String body)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(DATE_SELECTED, date);
    initialValues.put(WEIGHT_INPUT, weight);
    initialValues.put(REPS_INPUT, reps);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

I know I am just missing something simple and any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Have You created this database sometimes before and added REPS_INPUT later? If yes, the database still exists, if You don´t have uninstalled the app (or deleted database from where You saved it). try to start from zero, delete Your app and reinstall it. If database is stored on external storage, delete database

Comment: Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`? If so, did you add the `reps` column to the create string after you originally created the table?

Comment: I wasn't opening the database correctly. I added my open to the constructor and I'm not getting any errors anymore.

Comment: I haven't gotten it to display correctly yet but that's a whole other issue. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

The SQLite error states that, "table exercises has no column named reps."

Comment: Yep, I think that's fairly obvious but your answer doesn't answer why it's happening.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo when the table was created. Just trying to point the guy in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't have open here: public CalendarDBAdapter(Context ctx)
 {
  this.mCtx = ctx;
  open();
 }